# A question about the error of sqlite:no such column

Tags: sqlite

## When I use the sqlite3 -init ex.sql in Windiws PowerShell,an error says:

```
Parse error near line 6: no such column: ostrich
  le"   , "10"        , 4          UNION     SELECT "ostrich"     , "500"
                                      error here ---^
```

### in my ex.sql ,just coding

```
CREATE TABLE animals AS
    SELECT "dog" AS name, "20" AS weight, 4 AS legs  UNION
    SELECT "cat"         , "10"         , 4          UNION
    SELECT "penguin"     , "300"        , 2          UNION
    SELECT "t-rex"       , "12000"      , 2          UNION
    SELECT "parrot"      , "6"          , 2          UNION
    SELECT "crocodile"   , "10"         , 4          UNION
    SELECT "ostrich"     , "500"        , 2;
```

### Please,I just started learning SQL and This question has been bothering me for a long time

Comment: Your code works fine: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oSGKP3Hafwc8VxvYevx9J8/0 Are you sure that you are using SQLite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short `"ostrich"` as used is considered to be an indetifier of a  column name. `'ostrich'` would be taken as a literal value as intended.

- as would "crocodile", "parrot" .... it's just that "ostrich", even though it is the last such occurrence, is the first reported on.

As per:-

> A string constant is formed by enclosing the string in single quotes ('). A single quote within the string can be encoded by putting two single quotes in a row - as in Pascal. C-style escapes using the backslash character are not supported because they are not standard SQL. https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#literal_values_constants_

More on the double v single quote here:- https://www.sqlite.org/quirks.html#double_quoted_string_literals_are_accepted.

What you want is to use:-

```
CREATE TABLE animals AS
    SELECT 'dog' AS name, '20' AS weight, 4 AS legs  UNION
    SELECT 'cat'         , '10'         , 4          UNION
    SELECT 'penguin'     , '300'        , 2          UNION
    SELECT 't-rex'       , '12000'      , 2          UNION
    SELECT 'parrot'      , '6'          , 2          UNION
    SELECT 'crocodile'   , '10'         , 4          UNION
    SELECT 'ostrich'     , '500'        , 2;
```